# optimize integer validation

Tags: c#, object-oriented, validation, integer

I have some classes with properties, wich could only have numeric values in a given range (e.g. 0 to 8). This should be validated and wrong values prevented with an exception. The given behavior may be implemented without duplicating the given code.

There are some [ValidatorAttributes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.integervalidatorattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) in C# but I can't get them to running. They don't seem to prevent the assignment with wrong values in a normal class.

My current solution is to copy paste this snippet for every attribute. But copy paste is not perfect:

```
private short _index;
public short Index
{
    get => this._index;
    private set
    {
        const short min = 0;
        const short max = 8;
        if (value < min || max < value)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The passed value is not between " + min + "  and " + max + " (values included)");
        }
        this._index = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: The attribute itself does not execute any code. A certain engine must use the code described in this attribute. The attribute you mentioned is used by the configuration engine. And, for example, this [Range](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute?view=net-5.0) attribute is used by the ASP.NET engine.

Comment: You can use AOP if you want to add elegant validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the lines of code to copy/paste, you could create a helper method:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void EnsureIsInRange(short value, short min, short max)
    {
        if (value < min || max < value)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The passed value is not between " + min + "  and " + max + " (values included)");
        }
    }
}
```

or more generic:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void EnsureIsInRange<T>(T value, T min, T max) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(min) != 1 || value.CompareTo(max) != -1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("The passed value is not between " + min + "  and " + max + " (values included)");
        }
    }
}
```

// usage:

```
private short _index;
public short Index
{
    get => this._index;
    private set
    {
        Helper.EnsureIsInRange(value, 0, 8);
        this._index = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It thats what I need.